# Do in app purchases need an extra barrier before purchasing in apps design for kids?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I would like to implement some in app purchases in my app which parents would need to purchase for their children. Do I need to implement additional barriers as it's an app designed primarily for kids or is iCloud authentication sufficient?

In app purchases are new for me so want to make sure I get it right when putting them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is handled through the Apple account setup and device settings. Family sharing has already an [Ask to buy](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201089) features that requires purchases made by minors to be authorised by a parent.

Furthermore, [Restrictions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204396) can be set on any device to prevent purchases of any kind.

So, as a developer, you don't need to handle these purchases differently. Please beware that special conditions and privacy policy considerations are enforced for the Kids category according to the [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!